# Is it possible to add an Alias using a filter with wildcards in Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, alias

Here's what I have done so far...added an alias to a single doc:

```
x="15-44931"
es.indices.update_aliases({
"actions": [
   { "add":    { "index": 'job_old', "alias": x,"filter":{"term":{"path.virtual.keyword":"/15-44931/4.pdf"}}}}

    ]
  })
```

So the following just added the alias "15-44931 to the document with path.virtual="/15-44931/4.pdf". Is it possible to use a wildcard so it adds the alias to multiple docs using something like "/15-44931/*"?

I have tried:

```
{ "add":    { "index": 'job_old', "alias": x,"filter":{"term":{"path.virtual":"/15-44931/*"}}}}
```

and it isn't working...

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working:

```
{ "add":    { "index": 'job_old', "alias": x,"filter":{"regexp":{"path.virtual.keyword":"/"+x+".*"}}}}
```